# What is the consideration behind making RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE request twice?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, dynamic-linking

From my understanding of the use of `RTLD_DI_SERINFO` in [`dlinfo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html), the first call gives `dls_size` value that helps ensure the struct is large enough, but the second call is seemly doing nothing new but repeating computation of first call to fill out the two fields `dls_size` and `dls_cnt`. Besides, from the [code called](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.37.9000/source/elf/dl-load.c#L2298) by the dlopen [interface](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.37.9000/source/dlfcn/dlinfo.c#L63), I am unable to locate some code distinguishing the two calls and therefore my question is whether this two-step call sequence is something really necessary, or is it already enough to just copy over those stats, like by having a new request item called `RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE_COPY` to provide some forward compatibility from library author's viewpoint. The following code prints two exact same line on my machine.

```c
  Dl_serinfo dl_search_size;
  if (dlinfo(dl_handle, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, &dl_search_size)) {
    printf("dlinfo: %s while populating search info size", dlerror());
    return;
  }
  printf("%d %ld\n", dl_search_size.dls_cnt, dl_search_size.dls_size);
  Dl_serinfo *dl_search_info = (Dl_serinfo *)malloc(dl_search_size.dls_size);
  if (!dl_search_info) {
    perror("malloc");
    return;
  }
  if (dlinfo(dl_handle, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, dl_search_info)) {
    printf("dlinfo: %s while ", dlerror());
    return;
  }
  printf("%d %ld\n", dl_search_info->dls_cnt, dl_search_info->dls_size);
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for commenting but I think it explicitly said that I should do it twice 1. Use a RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE request to populate ... 2. Allocate a Dl_serinfo buffer of the correct size (dls_size). 3. Use a **further** RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE request to populate... Also you could check the example code that did this twice.

Comment: Okay I see it now. They do the second call with `RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE` to initialize the newly allocated structure. I don't see anything in the manual that specifies *why* it has to be done that way, as you could just as easily just copy the values from the first call.  You could always look at the `dlinfo` source to see if it contains any specific code that differs between the two calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the consideration behind making RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE request twice?

There *is no point* in doing *that*.

You call `dlinfo(..., RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, ...)` to get sufficient space so you can call `dlinfo(..., RTLD_DI_SERINFO, ...)`, i.e. to get the *actual* data you are interested in.

**Update:**

The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html) currently lists 4 steps:

1. Use a `RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE` request
2. Allocate a `Dl_serinfo` buffer of the correct size
3. Use a further `RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE` request
4. Use a `RTLD_DI_SERINFO` to obtain the library search paths.

Step 3 is clearly bogus/unnecessary. I am 99.99% sure it's a bug in the man page.

The *authoritative* description is the `glibc/manual/dynlink.texi` file, which says:

```
@item RTLD_DI_SERINFO
@itemx RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE
These requests can be used to obtain search path information for
@var{handle}.  For both requests, @var{arg} must point to a
@code{Dl_serinfo} object.  The @code{RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE} request must
be made first; it updates the @code{dls_size} and @code{dls_cnt} members
of the @code{Dl_serinfo} object.  The caller should then allocate memory
to store at least @code{dls_size} bytes and pass that buffer to a
@code{RTLD_DI_SERINFO} request.  This second request fills the
@code{dls_serpath} array.  The number of array elements was returned in
the @code{dls_cnt} member in the initial @code{RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE}
request.  The caller is responsible for freeing the allocated buffer.

This interface is prone to buffer overflows in multi-threaded processes
because the required size can change between the
@code{RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE} and @code{RTLD_DI_SERINFO} requests.
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting @employed-russian but please check the comments under question about the manpage explicitly asking for this.

Comment: Ok it is interesting that manpage is not part of glibc and they have their own documentation. Thanks a lot for pointing to this.